# Create new product variation and add selected variation to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Create new product with two variations and add selected to the cart

**Desired outcome:**
Form selects between variations and adds the corresponding variation to cart.

Current outcome:
The second variation is added to the cart regardless of which is selected

Notes: Adding the `variation_id` should be pretty straight forward but since the variation id has yet to be created I need a way to associate the variation terms in the form with the newly assigned `variation_id`

```
<form name="new-prod" method="post" action="">
<input type="radio" name="attribute_pa_size" value="11oz" id="pa_size_v_11oz">
<input type="radio" name="attribute_pa_size" value="15oz" checked="checked" id="pa_size">
```

PHP:

```
$post_size = $_POST['attribute_pa_size'];
```

Multiple variations created:

First Variation

```
$parent_id = $product_ID;
$variation = array(
'post_title'   => 'Product #' . $parent_id . ' Variation',
'post_content' => '',
'post_status'  => 'publish',
'post_parent'  => $parent_id,
'post_type'    => 'product_variation'
);
$variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', 21.95 );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', 21.95 );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_' . $mythis->size_tax, '15oz' );
WC_Product_Variable::sync( $parent_id );
```

Second Variation

```
$parent_id = $product_ID;
$variation = array(
'post_title'   => 'Product #' . $parent_id . ' Variation',
'post_content' => '',
'post_status'  => 'publish',
'post_parent'  => $parent_id,
'post_type'    => 'product_variation'
);
$variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', 18.95 );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', 18.95 );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_' . $mythis->size_tax, '11oz' );
WC_Product_Variable::sync( $parent_id );
```

Add variation to cart

```
$quantity     = 1;
$variation    = $post_size;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced all references of `$variation_id` with `$elevenvariation_id` for the first variation.

Then replaced the "add variation to cart" block with the following, and it managed to work from my initial testing:

```
  $quantity     = 1;
  $variation    = $post_size;

$answer = $_POST['attribute_pa_size'];  
if ($answer == "15oz") {          
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation  );   
}
    else {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity, $elevenvariation_id, $variation  );
        }
```